# Editing and creating things with address bar code?

Tags: php, http-get

How do I make it so that I can make a thing at the end of the address where the .php is and then tell it to do certain things. For example pull up a page like this:

sampardee.com/index.php?page=whatever

Help?

Anything else I could do with this?

Answer (score 5):

This is generally achieved with the global php array $_GET.  You can use it as an associative array to 'get' whatever variable you name in the url. For example your url above:

```
//this gives the $page variable the value 'whatever'
$page = $_GET['page'];

if($page == 'whatever'){
//do whatever
}
elseif($page == 'somethingelse'){
//do something else
}
```

Check out the php documentation for more information:

[$_GET documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

and there's a tutorial here:

[Tutorial using QUERY_STRING and _GET](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/php/php_p2.php)

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement over Brett's code:

```
if (array_key_exists('page', $_GET) === false)
{
    $_GET['page'] = 'defaultPage';
}

$page = $_GET['page'];

// ... Brett Bender's code here
```

Answer (score 1):

**$_GET** is usually used if you are sending the information to another page using the URL.

**$_POST** is usually used if you are sending the information from a form.

If you ever need to write your code so that it can accept information sent using both methods, you can use **$_REQUEST**. Make sure you check what information is being sent though, especially if you are using it with a database.

From your question it looks like you are using this to display different content on the page?

Perhaps you want to use something like a **switch** to allow only certain page names to be used?

i.e.

> $pageName=$_REQUEST['page'];
>
> switch($pageName){
>   case 'home':$include='home.php';break;
>   case 'about':$include='about.php';break;
>   case default:$include='error.php';break;
>   }
>   include($include);

This is a *really* simplified example, but unless the $page variable is either home or about, the website will display an error page.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I think you're asking how to use GET requests.

Make GET requests against any PHP page as follows:
www.mysite.com/page.php?key1=value1&key2=value2

Now, from within PHP, you'll be able to see key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2.

Access the GET hash from within PHP as follows:
$myVal1 = $_GET['key1'] #resolves to "value1"
$myVal2 = $_GET['key2'] #resolves to "value2"

From here, play with your GET variables as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The system of adding page parameters to a URL is know as HTTP GET (as distinct from HTTP POST, and some others less commonly used).

Take a look at this [W3 schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp) about GET in PHP and ahve a play about in getting parameters and using them in your PHP code.

Have fun!